# How to route and display a particular object from an array of objects from the database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

below is my routing code. I can able to route from displaylist to informationlist and in informationlist i am getting all the data from the database but i want to display one student display data based on their Id or something. What should i do now to do so??
And every time i need to display different student details.

this is my router.

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/students" component={Students}/>
    <Route path="/holidays" component={Calender}/>
    <Route path="/premontessori" component={Premontessori}/>
    <Route path="/createstudent" component={Createstudent}/>
    <Route path="/montessori1" component={Montessori1}/>
    <Route path="/montessori2" component={Montessori2}/>
    <Route path="/displaylist"  component={Displaylist}/>
    <Route path="/information" component={Information}/>
  </Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

this is my Link from displaylist to informationlist

```
<Link  to="/information" style={{textDecoration:'none'}} >
```

Answer (score 0):

A super naive implementation would look kinda like this

```
<Route path="/students/:id/" component={Student} />

const Student = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        var id = this.props.params.id;
        return MyAPIClient.get('/path-to-my-api/?studentId=' + id).then(function (data) { this.setState({student: data }.bind(this));
    },
    render: function() {
        // Render your HTML
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you give me some links to docs so that i can go through it in details

Comment: Here ya' go https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md#fetching-data